# Query performance is not what I would expect

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query across a big table (close to 50 million records) and a small table (maybe 1000 records on average) in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
UPDATE aa 
SET col1 = bb.col1, 
    col2 = bb.col2
FROM 
    tblBIG aa
INNER JOIN 
    #tempTblSmall bb ON aa.colMatchA = bb.colMatchA
                      AND aa.colMatchB = bb.colMatchB
                      AND aa.colMatchC = bb.colMatchC
                      AND aa.colMatchD = bb.colMatchD
WHERE
    aa.colMatchD >= @DateChanged
```

The query runs in around 10 seconds which is okay but not great, so I am trying to optimize it and came up with the following change:

```
UPDATE aa 
SET col1 = bb.col1, 
    col2 = bb.col2
FROM 
    tblBIG aa
INNER JOIN
    #tempTblSmall bb ON aa.colMatchA = bb.colMatchA
                       AND aa.colMatchB = bb.colMatchB
                       AND aa.colMatchC = bb.colMatchC
                       AND aa.colMatchD = bb.colMatchD
WHERE
    aa.colMatchA = @Param1
    AND aa.colMatchB = @Param2
    AND aa.colMatchD >= @DateChanged
```

This cut down the query run time drastically (basically immediate at this point), but I am not sure *why* this works. The temporary table `#tempTblSmall` is already restricted to `@Param1` and `@Param2`, so I would have assumed that I wouldn't need another set of where clauses.

I am happy that I managed to improve the performance, but I am curious to know if I got lucky and managed to put the query planner into a better estimation plan or if I just misunderstood how SQL Server plans the inner join and should be doing something like this going forward. I thought SQL Server would have an implicit where clause because of the join, but apparently restricting the large table is done before the join?

Comment: What indexes does the table have?  Probably can used a different index in the 2nd plan.

Comment: Look at the execution plan of both.  It should help you understand the difference.    Logically you've imposed more limits on the second query which if indexed, would reduce the set of data the update needs to execute upon.  thus would be faster.  on a inner join limits in where clause may be applied before the join itself.. Not so in outer joins.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Out of the two indexes that it uses, one of them is basically tailored to the second query whereas the other one is a pretty wide index. The number of updated records is exactly the same, just one has to scan a lot more rows. Thanks @Hogan. and xQbert

Comment: "but apparently restricting the large table is done before the join?" Yep. but only on inner joins and the result set is not impacted by when the limit is applied, but the processing time is.  (thus the generated result set can be limited before the join, reducing the number of records the system has to join on).  This can vary from engine to engine and version to version in the early days; but is pretty stable now at this point.

Comment: Checking for `WHERE aa.colMatchD >= @DateChanged` is redundant _if_ you ensure that the dates in `#tempTblSmall ` all meet that criterion. Does `tblBIG` have an index on `colMatchD`, `colMatchA`, `colMatchB` and `colMatchC`? That is a _single_ index where all of the columns are present. If you do want to use a comparison on the date column other than strict equality, e.g. `>=`, then it should be the first column in the index.

Answer (score 0):

So the temporary table is limited to  @Param2  @DateChanged

Those condition are on the big table

And I would pull the conditions into the join

```
Update aa 
   set aa.col1 = bb.col1, 
       aa.col2 = bb.col2
  from tblBIG aa
  join #tempTblSmall bb
    on aa.colMatchA = bb.colMatchA
   and aa.colMatchB = bb.colMatchB
   and aa.colMatchC = bb.colMatchC
   and aa.colMatchD = bb.colMatchD
   and aa.colMatchA =  @Param1
   and aa.colMatchB =  @Param2
   and aa.colMatchD >= @DateChanged
   and (aa.col1 <> bb.col1 or aa.col2 <> bb.col2)
```

Comment: I will try it out, but do you know off hand if putting the condition in the join is an optimization? Or is it just a stylistic preference?

Comment: I have seen many cases where the query optimizer got smarter in the join.  On a single join it typically will be the same.